# web information extraction

Tags: information-retrieval

I want to create a shopping search engine that shows products from many websites and I wonder how can I retrieve information about products from those sites. 
I am not interested in search engine part but in extracting product information from web pages in an automated manner using auto-generated templates. Does anybody knows some good algorithms for this / papers to read..

Comment: What do you mean 'using auto-generated templates'?  Like a language for defining how a robot should scrape a specific page or site?

Comment: Maybe I have not express well. I want an algorithm or technique to detect the template behind web page and extract data according to that template.

Comment: You may want to have a look at what information extraction is (http://www.isweb.uni-koblenz.de/files/ssms09/SSMS_Slides/ciravegna-IE%20text.pdf is a great start). You may consider how "many" websites you are trying to index, maybe writing a dedicated parser for each one is not a huge amount of work?

Answer (score 0):

[Dapper](http://open.dapper.net/dapperDemo/) looks pretty close to what you are looking for. http://open.dapper.net/